# TopMost application - make it decrease oppacity when have something on back

Tags: c#, topmost

First of all sorry about my english.
What I really want to learn is a way to make my TopMost application "understand" that it has something on its back so i could than make it decrease her oppacity %.

Hope you understand my question. ;)
Regards

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to be able to test whether or not another form of your application is behind your TopMost form, and if so, decrease the opacity of the TopMost form?  You realize, of course, that even though you'd be able to see the form in the background, you wouldn't be able to interact with it because of the TopMost form being in front...  =)

Comment: Yeah I know. And yes that it my question. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

While invoking the form, you could pass a parameter to its constructor determining whether some other form is already opened and if so, you could then decrease the opacity of the top most form. To find out how many forms are opened you could use

```
if(Application.OpenForms.Count > 1)
    this.Opacity = 0.75;
else
  this.Opacity = 1.0;
```

Hope this help

Comment: FYI, this will decrease the opacity if there are any other forms open in your app - regardless of whether or not your main form is in front of them.

Comment: One could check that whether the form has focus or not, if yes applies the above code. What do you say Barlow?

Comment: So, what has happened: nothing lol. Cuz this will check how many forms of my application are running. Right? What are you thinking now? Again, thanks for your help =D